# JOTA - How to verify PoW is being done?

Tags: pow, attach-to-tangle

I'm using the JOTA : Library 0.9.11-SNAPSHOT API.

I have the example found at https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.java/blob/master/jota/src/test/java/jota/SendMessageTest.java working from an Eclipse JUnit run. I know PoW is a fundamental requirement for the Tangle, but how is this done when running an example like this? How to verify that PoW is being done?

I have been using server http://node03.iotatoken.nl:15265 for testing - I've sent 4000+ tryte zero balance message transactions, and have verified the transactions days later. All is working. PoW must have been done - right?

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Pow must have been done... but not locally.

To perform the POW locally, you need to setup an iotaClient with a object able to perform the pow locally.

You do this in the `@Setup` for your test with this line of code :

```
iotaClient = new IotaAPI.Builder().localPoW(new PearlDiverLocalPoW()).build();
```

This will create a client able to perform the pow locally (the default client requires a node offering to do the pow remotely)

Then you must simply follow the calls :

```
[SendMessageTest.java (line 42)]    iotaClient.sendTransfer(...)
[IotaAPI.java (line 825)]           sendTrytes(...)
[IotaAPI.java (line 239)]           attachToTangle(...)
[IotaAPICore.java (line 370)]       localPoW.performPoW(txn.toTrytes(), minWeightMagnitude);
[PearlDiverLocalPoW.java (line 16)] pearlDiver.search(trits, minWeightMagnitude, 0)
```

You can put a break point at IotaAPICore.java (line 370)

```
resultTrytes[i] = localPoW.performPoW(txn.toTrytes(), minWeightMagnitude);
```

and compare the trytes before `txn.toTrytes()` and after invocation of the pearlDiver : `resultTrytes[i]`

(be aware that running with debugger is most of time terribly slow with this kind of code)

Comment: Thank you Ben, it worked just as you said. I'm going to post another question